# how do I set the aws ssm send-command to not have an executionTime default of 3600 seconds?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I am able to configure TimeoutSeconds in my send-command statement itself (I'm using python boto3 sdk) but I can't configure the ExecutionTimeout from my send-command or the ssm document. The console has the option to configure all these timeout values, but I can't seem to from my code. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using schema 2.2, you need to give the timeoutSeconds parameter a value in seconds.

```
"inputs": {
  "timeoutSeconds": "3660",
  "runCommand": [
    "Start-Sleep -Seconds 3650"
    "Write-Out \"Done\""
  ]
}
```

If you are using schema 1.2 I believe the parameter you need is executionTimeout.